# Реализация Sherlock ActionBar вместе с TabACtivity

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android, activity

Возникла такая проблемка: был `layout` с `TabActivity` на нём и нужно добавить туда `ActionBar`, для версий *2.1+* необходимо ставить шерлока и из-за этот возник вопрос как  организовать наследование `Activity`, если и шерлок и табы требуют наследования от себя

Comment: посмотрите вот этот пример: [Android Actionbar Sherlock with Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640512/android-actionbar-sherlock-with-tabs)